# How to show image in an aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I'm using this

`<asp:Image ID="UserPicture" runat="server" />`

to show image in the aspx file and the code behind looks like this:

`string imagePath = "~/ProfilePictures/" + UsernameBox.Text;
 UserPicture.ImageUrl = imagePath;`

But after loading the page, the picture won't show up, only the default picture icon appears. Any suggestions how to do it properly?  (Maybe resize the image?)

Thanks

Comment: Does `UsernameBox.Text` contains the complete file name with extension?

Comment: look into your renderized  page markup

Comment: @Rahul Singh - Yep, I forgot to add the file extension, I'm stupid, but thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

User Server.MapPath() method:

```
string imagePath = "ProfilePictures/" + UsernameBox.Text;
```

Make sure `UsernameBox.Text` must be the xyz.jpg OR any of the file name with extension.

Comment: This would give the filename in the server's filesystem, which is *not* what you want in a webpage.

Comment: Can you please explain me more? I'm not understand your comment.

Comment: Your code would give a filename like `C:\website\ProfilePictures\something` - where that file is on the *server*. The browser would look on it's local disk, and of course can't find the file. Note that when you as developer try this, it seems to work because server and browser are then on the same machine.

Comment: You are right @HansKesting. Thank you. Let me update my answer.